# Computer Clustering

Tags: maas, cluster

I know this question has been asked earlier but am not able to get a simple step by step answer.
What I need is :

1. Create a seemless Cluster where I would Use 1 Laptop as Main PC where I can work on and use Other Laptops as Hardware Add-ons to provide extra Processing  Power and RAM and Hard Drive.
2. Purpose to do it is to provide resource to all Applications ( Ex. Chrome , VLC Player,Open Office )
3. Both laptop have Ethernet (which I would use to Bundle them) and switch wifi on only on Main PC.

Please let me know if this will require a server Installation of Ubuntu or a PC Distro.
Also steps to Achieve this.

Thanks,
Shashank